# How to have content in scrollable list row overflow to the edges of the screen in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a horizontal scroll view in a list row in SwiftUI. How do I have the content in the scroll view overflow to the edges of the screen?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Group {
                Label("Hello World", systemImage: "globe")
                    .background(.red)
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    LazyHStack {
                        ForEach(1..<100) { index in
                            Text("\(index)")
                                .padding()
                                .background(.red)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By bypassing the safe area in SwiftUI, you can stretch content to the screen's boundaries. The List view, however, automatically adds padding to the edges. You should think about utilizing a ScrollView rather than a List for your outermost view so that your content can spill over the edges, and use a VStack to hold your collection of views.

The following modifications should fix your issue:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Label("Hello World", systemImage: "globe")
                    .background(Color.red)
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    LazyHStack {
                        ForEach(1..<100) { index in
                            Text("\(index)")
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.red)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, -16)  // Negate default padding
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .horizontal)
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this approach is you lose the reusability of a List. I can do this easily in UIKit with UICollectionView in a UITableView but this seems really tricky in SwiftUI.